# Find out the DeveloperName of a Flow in Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow

I have a flow that is loading a Lightning Web Component. Is there a way for the LWC to find out what the name of the flow that is invoking it is without the flow passing a variable to the LWC?